# Expanding background outside grid-area

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have created a template using CSS grid:

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: '. content .' '. other-content .';
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 15em 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-area: content;
}

.content-bg-left,
.content-bg-right {
  background-color: blue;
}

.content-without-expanded-bg {
  background-color: green;
  grid-area: other-content;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="content-bg-left"></div>
  <div class="content">
    Something inside here
  </div>
  <div class="content-bg-right"></div>
  <div class="content-without-expanded-bg">
    Something else here
  </div>
</main>
```

What I don't like with the above setup is that there are empty elements hanging around. Is it possible to expand the background for `.content` element without the need for the empty `.content-bg-left` and `content-bg-right` elements? I still want `.content` to stay in the middle, so adding `grid-column: 1/-1;` is not an option.

Comment: I think there may be other posts that cover this matter in more detail. Temani Afif may be able to assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is pretty fine. We can get rid of extra `div`s, but by just changing them on `::before` and `::after`. This solution is more like hack, but it works for this task.

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: '. content .' '. other-content .';
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 15em 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-area: content;
  position: relative;
}

.content::before,
.content::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  width: 9999px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.content::before {
  right: 100%;
}

.content::after {
  left: 100%;
}

.content-without-expanded-bg {
  background-color: green;
  grid-area: other-content;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="content">
    Something inside here
  </div>
  <div class="content-without-expanded-bg">
    Something else here
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am after :)

Answer (score 1):

No need for extra HTML elements. No need for hacks.

CSS pseudo elements on the container are treated as grid items.

Just add this to your code:

```
main::before,
main::after {
  background-color: blue;
  content: "";
}
```

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: '. content .' '. other-content .';
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 15em 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: aqua;
}

main::before,
main::after {
  background-color: aqua;
  content: "";
}

.content-without-expanded-bg {
  grid-area: other-content;
  background-color: lightgreen;

}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="content">
    Something inside here
  </div>
  <div class="content-without-expanded-bg">
    Something else here
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Your solution would not work if I wanted another section with expanded background, but the idea in general works.